# The lower bound of "sdk: '>=1.24.1 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

[This is the error message i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnhMB.png)

Upgrade Dart SDK:

```
Upgrading Dart SDK version
```

Update Dependencies:

```
Reviewing my project's dependencies in the pubspec.yaml file.
```

I have tried all those options but i still get the error.May any one help to resolve the error, before it was working with null safely when i was running in ios

Answer (score 1):

Your pubspec.yaml needs to indicate that you are using version 3.0 or later. For example:

```
environment: 
  sdk: '^3.0.0'.
```

Then also update transparent_image to a version that supports null safety such as 2.0.1.

```
dependencies:
  transparent_image: ^2.0.1
```